# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.common.support'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I've already installed selenium using `pip install selenium` and am currently learning. But this happened:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH = "/Users/mattmac/Downloads/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.common.support'
```

Comment: Did you try with ```pip3 install selenium``` If Yes. so try with 
```from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait ```
```from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tested this. Seems like `support` does not need to be imported from `common`. Try importing like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("Your URL")
```

Answer (score 2):

As you wanted to import `WebDriverWait` the path isn't `selenium.webdriver.common.support.ui` but **`selenium.webdriver.support.ui`**. So effectively you need to replace the line:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

with:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Similarly  to import `expected_conditions` the path isn't `selenium.webdriver.common.support` but **`selenium.webdriver.support import`**. So effectively you need to replace the line:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

with:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```